# Unix command to search a line in a file and replace it

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ubuntu

I am trying to replace Config Files with the UnixCommandline without using an Editor like vi or nano.

An example could be:

```
ServerAdmin mail@example.com
```

I want to find the first or all lines that start with `ServerAdmin` and replace them with:

```
ServerAdmin secret@secret.com
```

Is there any command to do something like this? It should be possible with the standart UNIX tools also available in CygWin.

Comment: There you go, @Robin, you have the three stages of power: sed, awk and perl, in increasing order :-) One of them should be able to do it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sed -i 's/^ServerAdmin .*$/ServerAdmin secret@secret.com/' in-filename
```

Answer (score 2):

all the previous answers are correct but you can also do this with perl one liner

```
perl -p -i -e 's/ServerAdmin/ServerAdmin secret@secret.com/g' your_file_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` to do this, as per the following transcript:

```
pax> echo 'xyzzy plugh
ServerAdmin mail@example.com
twisty passages' | awk '
    /^ServerAdmin /{$0 = "ServerAdmin secret@secret.com"}{print}'

xyzzy plugh
ServerAdmin secret@secret.com
twisty passages
```

In other words, pipe the file through that `awk` command. It will find lines beginning with `"ServerAdmin<space>"` and modify those line before printing them. All lines *not* matching the pattern will be printed as is.

Obviously that's for your simple case as specified. If it turns out your input format is more complicated, you may need to adjust it but `awk` should still be up to the task.

And remember, if you want to capture the output to a *new* file rather than standard output, use:

```
awk 'above awk command goes here' currentFile >newFile
```

Comment: Thank you. I will go with @John Zwinks answer in the beginning because its easier.